# Conditional based pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I have searched for the answer on following question for a long time and didn't find anything except of restoring several tables. I have a directory based dump of postgresql database, what I want to do is perform restore of this database based on some data condition like: `WHERE [SomeField] > 10`. Is it possible? And if yes, could you please advice me how to do this? 
Thank you

Comment: No, you cannot do that. You will have to restore everything and extract what you need or delete what you don't want.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I found the following way -> extract dump as sql using -f option and remove not needed items in produced file. Is this the best approach for my needs or there is more efficient exists? thank you

Comment: This is an even more complicated and error-prone technique than the one I suggested.